# Why is my Epson L355 printing slightly faded?

Tags: hardware-failure, inkjet-printer

I recently bought an Epson L355, refurbished, on Ebay. It uses a continuous ink system, with a block of four refillable, non-replaceable ink cartridges outside, connected by rubber tubes.

The refurbishers hadn't noticed that there was some black ink in the yellow cartridge, so I had to wash it. I tried to dismantle the cartridge holder before realizing that there was an easier way to wash the yellow cartridge, so it's possible there is some air in a tube or that some tubes are a little squeezed.

The ink provided by the refurbishers to fill the cartridges (which arrived empty) wasn't genuine; it was from "Jetplay".

After following instructions to charge the ink, I printed two test pages, which came out with a faint, banded cyan mark only. I Googled for a while and repeated the process, at which point the printer started working properly, but with the black noticeably paler than my previous inkjet.

What's the most likely reason for this? What should I do to fix it; ideally, is there a software fix to just make it output more ink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a software issue; if I print a table in LibreOffice Writer, the lines are sharp.

Comment: This is sort of a surprising answer that doesn't seem to fit with the facts in the question.  Can you elaborate a little to tie them together?  Is the problem gone ?  Reproducible with software settings?  Prints correctly for somethings but not others?  Could it simply have been a need for the system to prime itself, or washing diluted a little ink that was the first used?

Comment: The black ink is now the right color, and not faded. I've still been seeing blurriness in PDF documents, but I have seen a LibreOffice table print with perfectly sharp lines, so I'm assuming that's a settings problem. It doesn't seriously affect me, so I'm not going to bother trying to fix it. Thanks very much for your interest though!